# nginx: send all requests to a single html page

Tags: javascript, nginx, history

Using nginx, I want to preserve the url, but actually load the same page no matter what.  I will use the url with `History.getState()` to route the requests in my javascript app.  It seems like it should be a simple thing to do?

```
location / {
    rewrite (.*) base.html break;
}
```

works, but redirects the url?  I still need the url, I just want to always use the same page.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question so the answer was ready for me :-)

Comment: You were almost there! 'rewrite ^ /base.html break;' should work, as pointed by @kolbyjack

Answer (score 236, accepted):

I think this will do it for you:

```
location / {
    try_files /base.html =404;
}
```

Comment: Note -- this will first check for the file requested, and if it's not there, it will serve base.html. So make sure that you've got no old extra files sitting around in your document root directory, or they'll get served directly if queried.

Comment: Using ``try_files '' /base.html;`` (empty string as the first argument to ``try_files``) avoids the lookup of a file called ``$uri``.

Comment: `try_files '' /base.html;` gave me a redirection problem and an internal server error, but modifying it to `try_files '' /base.html =404;` fixed that, if it helps anyone.

Answer (score 43):

Using just `try_files` didn't work for me - it caused a **rewrite or internal redirection cycle** error in my logs.

The Nginx docs had some additional details:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files

So I ended up using the following:

```
root /var/www/mysite;

location / {
    try_files $uri /base.html;
}

location = /base.html {
    expires 30s;
}
```

Comment: `try_files '' /base.html =404;` (see above)

Comment: This worked for me, but I actually did not need the `location = /base.html { expires 30s }` part.

Answer (score 26):

Your original rewrite should almost work.  I'm not sure why it would be redirecting, but I think what you really want is just

```
rewrite ^ /base.html break;
```

You should be able to put that in a location or directly in the server.

Answer (score 23):

This worked for me:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /base.html;
}
```

Comment: For a React application's production build, this works: `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;`. Why? Because the build comprises more other files, including static JavaScript and CSS files.

Comment: @ParamSiddharth What about getting 404 on refresh

Comment: How do you handle refreshing problem that gives 404 @Abhishek

Answer (score 20):

This worked for me:

```
location / {
    alias /path/to/my/indexfile/;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

This allowed me to create a catch-all URL for a javascript single-page app.  All static files like css, fonts, and javascript built by `npm run build`  will be found if they are in the same directory as `index.html`.

If the static files were in another directory, for some reason, you'd also need something like:

```
# Static pages generated by "npm run build"
location ~ ^/css/|^/fonts/|^/semantic/|^/static/ {
    alias /path/to/my/staticfiles/;
}
```

Comment: tks, this works for me, but the tailing slash at `alias` is important

Answer (score 9):

The correct way would be:

```
location / {
    rewrite (.*) base.html last;
}
```

Using `last` will make nginx find a new suitable `location` block according to the result of rewriting.

`try_files` is also a perfectly valid approach to this problem.