# Vue Router: URL does not load correct component while router-link does

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

My project uses Vue2 and Vue Router. I want to be able to load the component `Stats` by typing in the URL `http://example.com/stats`.

1. URL `http://example.com/stats` does not work, I'm redirected to `/` and it loads the `App` component
2. `<router-link :to="/stats">Go to stats</router-link>` works perfectly

I would like to know whether it is a Vue Router issue or a server configuration issue. I'd like to mention the fact that I experience this issue both in my `localhost` and my server using `nGinx`.

How could I fix this?

#### app.js:

```
const routes = [
  { path: '/', component: App },
  { path: '/stats', component: Stats },
  { path: "*", component: PageNotFound },
  { path: '/admin', meta: { requiresAdmin: true }, component: Admin},
  { path: "/not-authorized", component: NotAuthorized },
];

Vue.use(VueRouter);
    
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes,
})

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  data () {
    return {}
  },
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAdmin)) {
        if (!Store.state.isAdmin) {
            axios.post('/isAdmin').then((response) => {
                if(response.data.isAdmin){
                    next();
                }
                else {
                    next({
                        path: '/not-authorized',
                    })
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            next();
        }
    }
        else {
            next();
        }
    }
    else {
        next(); // make sure to always call next()!
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you also have `new Vue({ el: '#app', router })` somewhere?

Comment: Of course, sorry I just reduce the `app.js` to what it seemed to me important. I just updated it !

Comment: and you're calling `Vue.use(VueRouter)` at some point?

Comment: Yes I do. When I'm clicking on a `<router-link>` in my code I'm well redirected to my component. I updated the app.js file

Comment: What's the generated URI when you click on the link? Did you disable the `#` when instantiating the router?

Comment: Hmm this should be working. You don't get any errors in the console?

Comment: @tiagojpdias I think so since the `mode:history` is activated ?

Comment: @thanksd No error, I'm just simply redirected to `http://example.com`

Comment: Ah, you're redirected. I thought it was just loading the wrong component. Do you make a `router.beforeEach` call anywhere?

Comment: @thanksd OMG. I'm going to update the file again... Sorry for that. Yes I do use a `router.beforeEach` but it should not cause the issue should it ?

Comment: Can you comment out all of router.beforeEach and tell what happens then?

Comment: Same stuff is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did

`Route::get('/stats', 'HomeController@home');`

Answer (score 1):

Have you configured your web-server to return the same page regardless of the URL?
That way your app can load, and the URL is preserved so routing can take over and select the right component once it's loaded.

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7027686/7816087 suggests the following config for nginx:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /base.html;
}
```

Comment: This does not work, the URL is changed to `/` and then the `App` component is loaded

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Laravel routes and put this:

```
Route::any('{all}', function () {
    return view('index'); // if your main view is "index"
})
```

This will ensure that deep linking is working properly on all request handled by Laravel.

Comment: Where does OP mention Laravel?

Comment: @Phil I looked his previous posts and array of technologies. The accepted answer is also for Laravel.