# Create React App does not understand basename router when in production

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, create-react-app, react-router-dom

I am using `create-react-app` + `react router` to render a website on a subfolder (eg.: example.com/subfolder). Everything goes ok under development environment, but when I create a build to production, it does not understand the routes besides the initial `Home`component at "example.com/subfolder".

My code is this:

```
<Router basename="/subfolder/">
   <main>
      <Switch>
         <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
         <Route path="/route-one" component={ComponentOne}/>
         <Route path="/route-two" component={ComponentTwo}/>
         <Route component={error404} />
       </Switch>
    </main>
</Router>
```

When I try to access ComponentOne or ComponentTwo routes, it should go to example.com/subfolder/route-one but it is not.

In my package.json, the `homepage` property is set to `"."`

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What happens when you try example.com/subfolder/route-one in the browser, what Error message?

Comment: It gets an ngnix error. Maybe this configuration should be done in ngnix?

Comment: Your Webserver needs to ignore URL Parameters and always serve Index. Thats the Problem.

Comment: Hum...I'm not using parameters with my URL! And the server is pointing only to index :/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027636/nginx-send-all-requests-to-a-single-html-page